# Function that returns a value from firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hey guys so I need to get a field value from the firestore in order to use it in my code for some reason I created this method to get the value for me but it always returns Instance of 'Future' even though the field I'm returning is a String
anyone know what is the issue here

```
getTheNextUserId() async{
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collId');
var docSnapshot = await collection.doc('dId').get();
if (docSnapshot.exists) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;
  var uId = data['nextUserId'];
  return uId;
}
Future addUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName, int age,String email) async {
  final CollectionReference userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user');
  await userRef.doc(getTheNextUserId.toString()).set({
  'first name': firstName,
  'last name': lastName,
  'age': age,
  'email': email,
  'count': 10,});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your getTheNextUserId to this:

```
Future<String> getTheNextUserId {
...
}
```

then do this in addUserDetails:

```
var str = await getTheNextUserId();

await userRef.doc(str).set({
  'first name': firstName,
  'last name': lastName,
  'age': age,
  'email': email,
  'count': 10,});
```

Comment: same it says await applied to a not future

Comment: You don't need an await to get the collection reference, see my answer for the correct solution

Comment: Thank you so much man I've been struggling with this for days

Comment: Glad to hear that, if it was useful to you please approve and up vote it so other people could fine it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getTheNextUserId` is an `async` function, so it also must be awaited:

```
Future addUserDetails(String firstName, String lastName, int age,String email) async {
  final CollectionReference userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user');
  await userRef.doc((await getTheNextUserId()).toString()).set({ // in this line
    'first name': firstName,
    'last name': lastName,
    'age': age,
    'email': email,
    'count': 10,
});
```

Comment: it says await applied to string which is not Future

Comment: I had a typo, try this version